# Why is it "less than 9" and not "fewer than 9" when we're talking about exam marks and scores?

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

This might sound like too elementary of a question but it suddenly popped into my head and started eating me. Why "I don't wanna be less than 90." and not "I don't wanna be fewer than 90."? Aren't marks countable? (90, by the way, is a mark out of 100 students get here at the end of a course.)

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to score less than 90.  I don't want to score fewer than 90 points.

Comment: Because it's a score, not a count of apples.

Comment: cp "I don't want less than a car"; it has little bearing that the car is countable.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have unwittingly answered your own question; 90 *is* a mark (a percentage) so takes *less*. Somebody who thought of it as "I only got 90 points" could say "I don't want any fewer than that."

Comment: To add to this: Even if on a given exam, the realistically possible scores are discrete, in general percentages are not discrete.